# Как изменить шансы в лучшую сторону?

Tags: php

Всем добрый вечер, возник такой вопрос как изменить "шанс выпадения так скажем" в лучшую и худшую сторону, перепробовал много так и не понял, нуждаюсь в помощи.
Используется как режим игры Dice на сайте, может кто шарит.

```
try {
            $win = 0;
            $win_sum = 0;
            $profit = 0;
            $chance = round($perc, 2);
            $vip = 100/$chance;
            $rand = rand(0, 999999);

            if($sum == round($sum*$vip, 2)) {
                DB::rollback();
                return response()->json(['type' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Ваша ставка равна выигрышу!']);
            }
            
            if($chance > 80) $prod = 5;
            elseif($chance > 60 && $chance <= 80) $prod = 20;
            elseif($chance > 40 && $chance <= 60) $prod = 35;
            elseif($chance > 20 && $chance <= 40) $prod = 50;
            elseif($chance > 10 && $chance <= 20) $prod = 70;
            elseif($chance > 5 && $chance <= 10) $prod = 80;
            elseif($chance <= 5) $prod = 95 ;
            
            if($type == 'min') {
                $generate = floor($chance/100*999999);
                if(mt_rand(1, 100) <= $prod) {
                    while(in_array($rand, range(0, $generate))) {
                        $rand = rand(0, 999999);
                    }
                }
                if($this->user->is_youtuber && mt_rand(1, 100) > 60) $rand = rand(0, $generate);
                if(in_array($rand, range(0, $generate))) $win = 1;
            }
            if($type == 'max') {
                $generate = round(999999-$chance/100*999999);
                if(mt_rand(1, 100) <= $prod) {
                    while(in_array($rand, range($generate, 999999))) {
                        $rand = rand(0, 999999);
                    }
                }
                if($this->user->is_youtuber && mt_rand(1, 100) > 60) $rand = rand($generate, 999999);
                if(in_array($rand, range($generate, 999999))) $win = 1;
            }
```

Comment: не хотите ли объяснить, что за задачу решает ваш код?

Comment: Используется как режим игры на сайте, нужно чтобы win = 1 "выпадал" чаще объясню так

Comment: вы примерно сейчас говорите "у меня двигатель на заводится", и при этом не считаете нужным указать, речь про бензопилу, мотоцикл, автомобиль, ракету или корабль. Причем возможно там двс, дизель, электромотор. Опишите саму предметную область и суть алгоритма словами. Желающих пытаться понять ваш код много не наберется.

Answer (score 0):

Измените значение переменной $chance.
Это шанс, число от 0 до 100.

```
try {
     $win = 0;
     $win_sum = 0;
     $profit = 0;
     $chance = 80;
```